# Visual Studio 2013 Express with update 3 stuck at Configuration step

Tags: visual-studio-2013

I am trying to install Microsoft Visual Studio Express 2013 with Update 3 for Windows. 
I have downloaded its iso image, and the started the installation. But it seems to be stuck at "Configuring your system, this may take a while" for more than 2-3 hours.

Does it usually takes this much time only, is it normal, or there seems to be a problem with the iso file?
How much time does it usually take for complete installation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Visual studio generally takes a lot of time as it is the new update, wait for some more time if it is still the same, cancel and try updating again.

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same problem, if you're visual Studio just stuck for to long like mine was, use alt-tab, to switch to another windows.

This might show a hidden windows with the next steps. Hope that can help you

Here's also some info that could help
[Visual Studio takes forever to start the first time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21179593/visual-studio-2013-take-forever-to-start-the-first-time)

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. 
Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: ok thanks, i will do it for the next time

Answer (score 0):

i recently downloaded the Visual Studio 2015 community and i agree that it takes much more time..... just keep your lappy away for installing and go away for doing some other stuff........it is going to take **3 hrs approx**